# Modifying a PDF file with java

Tags: java, pdf, velocity

i have a template with plain text, some tables and a few images, i want to fill several of that template with data from a Data base.
Is possible to open a pdf file in java an modify it? if it's possible, what (free)libraries i need (with documentation)? is compatible with apache velocity?

Comment: It is possible to modify PDFs, in Java and in other programming environments. But whether or not it is possible to do what you want depends on how your templates are built, how the library is expected to recognize which regions to fill, and which unspoken expectations you have: Do you expect automatic line breaks, table rows to expand in case of such line breaks, uneven column borders to be respected in such a case, additional pages to be generated in such field overflow cases, ...

Comment: Essentially PDF is a format for your use case only if the template contains its fields as AcroForm form fields; otherwise expand the template in some other format (e.g. some word processor format) and export to PDF.

Comment: i expect a few overflow cases, yes

Comment: *i expect a few overflow cases* - in that case, especially in case of page overflows, I advise **not to use PDF templates** because there generally is nothing in PDF that indicates which page decorations (headers and footers etc.) to insert, whether there are different margins and decorations for odd or even pages, ... If there is nothing fancy like that, no header, no footers, no nothing, you might get along with PDF templates, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's A JAVA PDF framework that have a lot of stuff modifying exiting PDF is one of them

Check this

http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=275

Answer (score 0):

http://www.gnostice.com/PDFOne_Java.asp

It's ironic that their website is built in asp.net